# Algorithm - formatting

Tags: formatting, algorithm2e

I need some help with formatting my algorithm. What I have so far is this:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{sig-alternate}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoNoLine
 \KwData{The original list \textbf{R}, $ N \leq n $}
 \KwResult{The re-ranked list \textbf{S}}
 S = <>\;
 \While{ |S| < N }  {\do  {$i^{*} = argmax_{i\in R\setminus S} f_{obj}(i,S,u)$   \;
     S = S $ \circ i^{*}$\;
     R = R $ \setminus {i^{*}}$  \;
    \Return{S}\;
}
\
}
\caption{The greedy strategy.}
\label{Algorithm1}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I am using `algorithm2e` package with options `linesnumbered` and `ruled`. 
The desired result looks something like this:

[image: the result]

The `ruled` option makes the caption appear at the top of the algorithm, but I need it to be at the bottom. Furthermore, in my document, the `Return` statement appears before the `end` statement. How can I exchange these? 
This is how my document looks like so far:
[image: my example]

Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` Please do not post code as an image but as real code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly ugly answer, but it matches your need. I added a `\hrulealg` macro so you can manually place some horizontal lines where you need them, and removed the `ruled` option. The `\Return` wall was placed inside the second argument of the `\While`, hence its former position before the `end`

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\hrulealg}[0]{\vspace{1mm} \hrule \vspace{1mm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoNoLine
\hrulealg
 \KwData{The original list \textbf{R}, $ N \leq n $}
 \KwResult{The re-ranked list \textbf{S}}
\hrulealg
 S = <>\;
 \While{ |S| < N }  {\do  {$i^{*} = argmax_{i\in R\setminus S} f_{obj}(i,S,u)$   \;
     S = S $ \circ i^{*}$\;
     R = R $ \setminus {i^{*}}$  \;
}
}
\Return{S}\;
\hrulealg
\caption{The greedy strategy.}
\label{Algorithm1}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

There are some small differences in my output due to the use of the `article` class instead of `sig-alternate` which I do not have.

[image]