# How to separate input output from main algorithm part and add end word in if statement?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

In the below image, I want to add two things

1. A  horizontal line after output which separate input-output from main part of algorithm
2. I want end word (line 5) at the vertical line from if statement.

See code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\textbf{Input} : A graph $G$\;
\textbf{Find} : Graph and its color\\
 \uIf{Complement o}{
 Do nothng \\~\\
 }

 Do different things here

\caption{ \textsc{ Algorithm Graph  }}
\label{algo8}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a piece of answer:

-You explicitely ask for no `end` word when calling `\uIf{}{}`, replacing this call with `\If{}{}` does what you want.

-To add a horizontal line inside the `algorithm` you can use the solution proposed in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458615/141947). The custom macro is `\hrulealg`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}
\newcommand{\hrulealg}[0]{\vspace{1mm} \hrule \vspace{1mm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\textbf{Input} : A graph $G$\;
\textbf{Find} : Graph and its color\\
 \If{Complement o}{
 Do nothing
 }
 \hrulealg
 Do different things here

\caption{ \textsc{ Algorithm Graph  }}
\label{algo8}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have upvoted you for your work. Very good. I like it.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks ! I am just wondering what would be a better way to center the `hrule` so that it is vertically centered between previous and next lines